# PostgreSQL UPDATE all rows in an array to something while updating all rows NOT in array to something else

Tags: postgresql

I have a query that seems to work:

```
UPDATE questions SET active=TRUE WHERE id=ANY ([1, 5, 7]);
```

But I also want to set all other rows to `active=FALSE`

Essentially, I want to do the equivalent of running these two lines

```
UPDATE questions SET active=FALSE;
UPDATE questions SET active=TRUE WHERE id=ANY ([1, 5, 7]);
```

But I would like to accomplish this in a single query if possible. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the condition as a Boolean value to set:

```
UPDATE questions SET active = (id = ANY(array[1, 5, 7]));
```